# Where can I see some good examples of what WPF is capable of?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

What is some good software that is written with WPF?

I keep hearing about what it can do.  I would like to see it in action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some samples

- http://bigpicture.vertigo.com/obama/
- http://www.photosuru.com/
- http://seattlepi.nwsource.com/newsreader/

Also take a look at [scott hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CategoryView.aspx?category=WPF) blog filtered by WPF tag, he writes very good articles and he also has [podcasts](http://www.hanselminutes.com/)

Comment: That first site sure was a show, made my web browser eat additional 350 megs of RAM and then grind to halt :P

Comment: The first one is Silverlight.  While it is related to WPF, they are not the same.

Comment: Most of the links are broken

Comment: this is a very old question, the links are not relevant anymore, but I can't delete the answer since this is the accepted answer. @Alex can you please remove this from the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.actiprosoftware.com/support/ResourceGuides/WPF/ViewCategory.aspx?ResourceGuideCategoryID=26) lists quite a lot of WPF applications (many from [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com), but also from various other sources).

Answer (score 1):

Billy Hollis has a great example on DNRTV

http://perseus.franklins.net/dnrtvplayer/player.aspx?ShowNum=0115

Answer (score 1):

[MS Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/products/2010/default.mspx) is written in WPF!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways of developing for [Microsoft Surface](http://www.surface.com/) is through WPF. So any of the Surface examples might help show possibilities.